# How to create a chrome extension and getting error when setting up service worker

Tags: chromium

So here is the problem, I am new to chrome extensions, And now trying to create a new one. but unfortunately my extension is not running  here is the error I get,

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onCompleted')

And this is the code in the service worker

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(async () => {
  const filter = {
    url: [
      {
        urlMatches: 'https://www.google.com/',
      },
    ],
  };
  chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(() => {

    console.info("The user has loaded my favorite website!");

  }, filter);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?